# find duplicate with lowest value LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, erp

I have a small app that is linked to a SQL table.
That particular table has the following fields:

- key1(P. key)
- shortchar05
- number03
- number04
- number05

This app is to keep the stock updated.

So for `key1=1`, I enter `item1` in `shortchar05`, `number05` (total) I'll have `5` for example. `number04` (this is used for how many `item1` I have issued) and `number03` should be updated stock (difference between `number05` and `number04`).

I know how to make the app work if values of `shortchar05` are distinct (e.g. `item1`, `item2`, `item3` etc.), but that's not what I am interested in.

What if I have the following situation:

```
key1 shortchar05 number05 number04 number03
===========================================
1    item1          5        3        2
2    item2          7        4        3
3    item3          8        2        6
```

Now if I am creating the next `key1` with value 4 but want to select `item1` and now the total would be `2` which would go in `number05` and I want to issue 1 piece of `item1`.

```
key1 shortchar05 number05 number04 number03
===========================================
4    item1          2        1        1
```

For `key1=5` I want to select `item1` again, so what I would like to have selected is the `item1` with the lowest value from column `number03` (`key=4` and not `key1=1`)

```
key1 shortchar05 number05 number04 number03
===========================================
5    item1          1        0        1
```

This is what I would like to have, for n number of items, if I select itemX, I'd like to display the duplicate itemX with lowest value in `number03` (that would be the updated total)

I hope I have been clear enough
Thank you!

This is simply done when creating a new key1 and entering a new distinct item

```
foreach (var ttUD04_R in ttUD04)
{
    var ttUD04_Recss = (from ttUD04_Row in Db.UD04 where ttUD04_Row.Company == Session.CompanyID orderby ttUD04_Row.Number03 ascending select ttUD04_Row).FirstOrDefault();
    if (ttUD04_Recss != null)
    {           
        ttUD04_R.Number05 = ttUD04_Recss.Number03;
        ttUD04_R.Number03 = (Convert.ToInt32(ttUD04_R.Number05) - Convert.ToInt32(ttUD04_R.Number04));
    }
}
```

Comment: You talk about a lot of stuff that does not make sense and then you don't ask a question ... do you have a question?

Comment: how to select itemX(even if duplicate) with lowest value in number03?
How does that not make sense? I have explained, not talked about a lot of stuff! If you don't want to help fine, don't do it, but don't tell me that it is non sense.

Answer (score 1):

This query will find ONLY duplicate values and select only the smallest value:

```
var duplicateMin = (yourTable.GroupBy(x=>x).Where(g=>g.Count()>1).Select(y=>y.DuplicateValue)).Min();
```

The variable naming in your code looks terrible, it's just about close to impossible to read after you. Please consider renaming your variables. I mean just look at your names: `ttUD04_R`, `ttUD04`, `ttUD04_Recss`, `Number05`, `Number03`. This makes no sense at all and I can guarantee you that anyone else that will try to read after you will have absolutely no idea what you're doing. And it seems like you don't either.

I'd suggest renaming them to something more sensible like `stockItems`, `updatedStock`, `itemStock`.

Comment: Thanks Peroxy, yes you're right I should have renamed them, instead of using as they are in my table.
That's how those are defined in my Epicor table, so that's why I kept them like that. For others it might be confusing, but for me it's quite good.
I appreciate!

Comment: Peroxy I have tried your solution but it does not contain a definition for DuplicateValue
is there a special reference?

Comment: Well yeah, `DuplicateValue` is something I came up with, I have no idea what duplicate value you're looking for. It should be named like: `y => y.YourValueName`.

Comment: well, a random value from column shortchar05

Answer (score 0):

> how to select itemX(even if duplicate) with lowest value in number03?

It does matter how you state it, for example if I state it like this:

Select lowest value for a field (in this case number03) from all items that match a criteria (in this case shortchar05 = 'item1')

Then the translation to linq is simple

All items that match the criteria:

```
var result = sourceList.Where(x => x.shortchar05 == 'item1');
```

Lowest value of number03 field -- order by that field and take the first one:

```
var result = sourceList.Where(x => x.shortchar05 == 'item1')
                       .OrderByDescending(x => x.number03)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I understood what you have said, but the thing is (perhaps I did not make myself clear enough, sorry for that)
Let's say I have 4000 rows in my table, and multiple "item1", or multiple "item2" and so on.
For example, now I open my window and write into my text box(shortchar05) -->"item239"
What I would like to see is that it loads "item239" with lowest value stored in number03 column, even if it's 0.

Comment: @John -- that is what my code does.  Just change the where to the value or variable you need `x.shortchar05 == 'item1'`

Comment: no because it selects the highest value, and I need the lowest one.
If I select FirstOrDefault and ordering ascending, it already assumes the value from number03 as 0, once a new row is created in the table.

Comment: @John - there is no table.  If you want lowest value do `OrderBy`, if you max value do `OrderByDescending` -- what is the issue here?

Comment: Hogan, yes there is, if you checked what I have stated in my description, you would have seen what I mean.
When I create a new key1(primary key) I may enter a new item or enter a previously stored item.
I know what OrderBy and OrderByDescending do, and I would need the min value stored in column number03 to be passed into shortchar05 in case an existing item is selected (when a new key1 is created -->new row in my table)
Now, with the new row created, with OrderBy, the min value would be 0, and I do not want that, but min value of number03 from current key1-1(first key1 before my current one).

Comment: @John - you continue to make no sense.  "when an existing item is selected" and "when new key1 is created" don't really mean anything.

Comment: Hogan, not at all, it does make sense, perhaps you are not understanding what I mean. It's all right, I appreciate your help anyway.

Comment: @John -- well typically a question on SO is answered in 10 mins -- yours has been here for almost a week.  I expect you question hasn't been answered because no one understands your question.  I would review the "How to ask" and "what makes a good question" sections of the help and FAQ if you want this resource to be of use to you.  Telling me (and everyone else) we are wrong won't get you far.

Comment: Hogan, I never said you are wrong and I appreciate you help!
Your answer helped me a lot in fact, I made it work yesterday.
Thanks!